# NHibernate and potential caching problems

Tags: wcf, nhibernate

Ok so I have an n tiered model. (WPF, Asp.Net, etc) to backend services via WCF.  These services use NHibernate to communicate with the database.  Some of these services will be run in InstanceContextMode.Single mode.

**Questions:**

1. In singleton service instances should I try to utilize 1 session object for the entire time the wcf service is alive to get the most out of my cache?
2. If I use 1 session instance in this singleton instance and never create new ones I assume I have to worry about eventually removing cached entities from the session or dumping it all together to avoid performance issues with the session?
3. Is it a good idea at all to use the session in this way for a singleton wcf service?  It seems like it would be if I want to utilize caching.
4. Should I utilize 2nd level cache in a scenario like this?
5. Outside of this scenario when should I avoid caching?  I would assume that I would want to avoid it in any sort of batching scenario where a large number of objects are created/updated and never really used again outside of the creation or updates.
6. Are items automatically cached in session when I create/read/update/delete or do I need to specify something in the mapping files or configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1-3: As far as I know, ISession objects are supposed to be light-weight, short-lived objects, which live only for the duration for which they're needed. I would advise AGAINST using the same ISession object for the whole lifetime of your service.
What I would suggest instead is using the same ISeessionFactory instance, and creating new ISessions from it as necessary (you can try something similar to Session-Per-Request pattern).
If you enable 2nd level cache, you can have all the benefits of caching in this scenario.

5 Yep, pretty much. Also remember that 2nd level cache instance is per **ISessionFactory instance**. that means that if you're using more than 1 ISessionFactory instance you'll have a lot of problems with your cache.

6 for 1st level cache you don't need to define anything.
for 2nd level cache you need to enable the cache when you configure nHibernate (fluently, in my case):

```
.Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache()
                                    .ProviderClass(
                                    isWeb ? typeof(NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2.SysCacheProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName //in web environment- use sysCache2
                                        : typeof(NHibernate.Cache.HashtableCacheProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName //in dev environmet- use stupid cache
                                    )) 
                          )
```

and specify for each entity and each collection that you want to enable cache for them:

```
mapping.Cache.ReadWrite().Region("myRegion");
```

and for a collection:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Something)
.Cache.ReadWrite().Region("myRegion");
```

Comment: If I use 2nd level cache do I need to worry about #2 above? Also if I define my entities with caching while I still be able to enable/disable this behavior via config?

Comment: in principal, no- nHibernate controls the cache in terms of validating / invalidating, emptying etc. and yes- caching is configurable (the fluent code I posted can be written as XML configuration, of course).